# Elasticsearch - Pick up a new property with calculation in bulk

Tags: json, elasticsearch

I'm trying to wrap my head around how ES works, but don't seem to succeed. I'd like it to read JSON files and append a new property to each entry via calculating a value from the existing ones. What would be the syntax for this? I can't seem to put together the information from the documentation to get it to work. Thank you!

I'm trying to do something like

```
POST /mystuff/1/_update
{
"doc": {
     "recency": (DateTime.now().getMillis() - doc['maxdate'].value)/(24*60*60*1000)
     }
}
```

to all the docs under `/mystuff`. (This obviusly doesn't work.)

[EDIT] Sample input:

```
PUT /mystuff/1
{
...
  "maxdate": "2016-06-14",
...
}
```

ES Version: 2.3.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `_update_by_query` API by Elasticsearch to update more than one document. You can read more about that [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html).

Your code will change in following way

```
POST mystuff/_update_by_query
{
  "script": {
    "inline": "ctx._source.recency = (DateTime.now().getMillis() - DateTime.parse(ctx._source.maxdate).getMillis())/(24*60*60*1000)"
  },
  "query": {
    "match_all": {
    }
  }
}
```

You should have script inline and script update enabled for this to work.

Comment: Nice! didn't know something like this existed :D

Comment: @VishalRao its a new experimental API, but is working fine for me, other way would be to update complete documents one by one.

Comment: Thank you! For some reason, I get `missing_method_error` for this: `"No signature of method: java.lang.Long.minus() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [2014-07-16]\nPossible solutions: minus(java.lang.Character), minus(java.lang.Number), plus(java.lang.String), find(), min(long, long), signum(long)"`. Any idea how to resolve it?

Comment: Can you post your elasticsearch version and a sample document which you have indexed. It's possibly due to performing - on string

Comment: Also, it's trying to use groovy, is that OK? `failed to run inline script [ctx._source.recency = (DateTime.now().getMillis() - ctx._source.maxdate)/(24*60*60*1000)] using lang [groovy]`
 I thought I read somewhere that they switched to something new. switched to

Comment: default scripting language is groovy, the above script would work if your data is modeled properly. Or you can put a check to perform operation only in integers or floats.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117392/discussion-between-sumit-kumar-and-lte).

Comment: @SumitKumar is there a default date format Elasticsearch recognizes automatically? Or do I have to make a mapping before uploading data?